# Split string with sliding window

Tags: python

How can I split a string into Nth length based on a list of words?

For example:

```
list_of_words = ["1 2", "1 2 3", "1 2 3 4"]

string = ["1 2 3 4"]

for i in list_of_words:
    split_size = len(i)
    # split string into n part according to the split_size

# Example: 
# For "1 2 3"
# Output would be: ["1 2 3"], ["2 3 4"] 

# For "1 2"
# Output would be: ["1 2"], ["2 3"], ["3 4"]
```

Comment: Your 1st example output appears to be wrong.

Comment: `split_size` should not be `len(i)`, since the split size for "1 2 3" would then be 5 (instead of 3). You want to do `split_size = len(i.split(" "))` (preferably outside of the for loop to optimizate). You could also arithmetically determine it from the length, so `split_size = len(i) // 2 + 1`

Comment: Why did you make list_of_words = ["1 2", "1 2 3", "1 2 3 4"] rather than, say, [2, 3, 4] to indicate how wide the sliding window is?

Comment: Do you want to split the string by the `len(i)` or by the last value of the string `i`? Is this a valid output for "1 2 3": ["1 2 3", "2 3 4", "3 4 1", "4 1 2"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_of_words = ["1 2", "1 2 3", "1 2 3 4"]
string = ["1 2 3 4"]

for i in list_of_words:
    split_size = len(i)
    lst = []
    for n in range(len(list_of_words)):
        if n * 2 + split_size <= len(string[0]): # it's the whole window?
            lst.append(string[0][n * 2: n * 2 + split_size]) # n*2 because of spaces between digits
    print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['1 2', '2 3', '3 4']
['1 2 3', '2 3 4']
['1 2 3 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_words = ["1 2", "1 2 3", "1 2 3 4"]

string = ["1 2 3 4"]
digits = "".join(string[0].split(" "))

for i in list_of_words:
    result = [] 
    split_size = len(i) // 2 + 1
    j = 0
    while j + split_size < len(digits) + 1:
        result.append(" ".join(digits[j:j+split_size]))
        j += 1
        
    print(result)
```

#### Output:

```
['1 2', '2 3', '3 4']
['1 2 3', '2 3 4']
['1 2 3 4']
```

As a note, the code would be much cleaner if the input data was better structured. Pre-processing could be done to bring it into a meaningful shape. For example, the `list_of_words` list could be pre-processed to give a list of the window sizes:

```
list_of_words = ["1 2", "1 2 3", "1 2 3 4"]

window_sizes = [len(word) // 2 + 1 for word in list_of_words]
```

Comment: This answer has been tested, and produces the output above.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you probably want something along these lines:

```
string_arr = "1 2 3 4".split(" ")

for length in range(2, 4):
    iters = len(string_arr) - length + 1
    for i in range(iters):
        print(" ".join(string_arr[i:i+length]))
```

The `range(2, 4)` corresponds to the lengths of your lists in the `list_of_words`. You then know from your `string` that you can have a maximum number of iterations as you move the window equal to the length of `string` minus the length of the window. The `+ 1` makes it easier to use the `range()` for the iteration of the window as you actually get values.

Obviously, you can add some plating to return the value or what have you, but this is the core of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should work out the input and output data format to make them contain meaningful and usable values.

As for the approach to return a list of sliding substring, you can do it like this:

```
size   = 3
word   = "ABCDE"
splits = [word[i:i+size] for i in range(len(word)-size+1)]

print(splits)
['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE']
```